# (android) Add a widget

Tags: android, android-appwidget

Well, i have created this widget

```
public class Widget extends AppWidgetProvider{
private SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat (
    "EEEEEEEEE\nd MMM yyyy");

public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    String now = formatter.format(new Date());

    RemoteViews updateViews = new RemoteViews (
            context.getPackageName() , R.layout.widget );
    updateViews.setTextViewText(R.id.text, now);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, updateViews);

    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

    }
}
```

It just shows the date, but i dont know how to add this class to my main program and finally show the widget on the home screen. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [link](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/days-xmas-widget-tutorial) to similar widget which gives days left to XMas.you can customize it to your need.

And widget would be displayed when user choose it from widget lists. So i think,you just have to worry for the data which widget would display.rest would be upto user whether to keep that widget on homescreen or not.

Comment: i read it but i cant find my way. Do you have any tutorial for creating widgets? I can create the class which creates the widget but i cant call it from my main program to add the widget and show it on home screen :/

Comment: That is the simplest example of creating widget( which displays days left). I think,you don't know how to show the widget on homescreen...if so,then long click on homescreen> widgets> choose your app name(Ex:it would be there for this-"days left to Xmas").it will show you the widget. you need to learn more about widget.please refer http://www.helloandroid.com/files/xmaswidget/android_howto-hellowidget.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Widget is basically a broadcast receiver. if you already have an application, then add this widget(broadcast receiver) to its manifest file.

Here is a link - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html

Answer (score 0):

### Days Left Widget ##    public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

```
private PendingIntent alarmIntent;
private final long alarmInterval = AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR;
public final String REFRESH_ACTION = "DAYSLEFT_WIDGET_REFRESH";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
    if (REFRESH_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        updateAllWidgets(context);
    }
}

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager widgetManager,
        int[] ids) {
    updateAllWidgets(context, widgetManager, ids);
    setupAlarm(context);
}

@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context) {
    teardownAlarm(context);
}

public static void updateAppWidget(Context context,
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int widgetId) {
    new WidgetRefresher(context, appWidgetManager).refresh(widgetId);
}

private void updateAllWidgets(Context context) {
    AppWidgetManager widgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);

    final String className = WidgetProvider.class.getName();
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(
            context.getPackageName(), className);

    final int[] widgetIds = widgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(componentName);
    updateAllWidgets(context, widgetManager, widgetIds);
}

private void updateAllWidgets(Context context,
        AppWidgetManager widgetManager, final int[] ids) {
    WidgetRefresher refresher = new WidgetRefresher(context, widgetManager);
    for (int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        refresher.refresh(ids[i]);
    }
}

private void setupAlarm(Context context) {
    if (alarmIntent == null) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(REFRESH_ACTION);

        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        final AlarmManager alarms = getAlarmManager(context);
        alarms.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, new Date().getTime(),
                alarmInterval, alarmIntent);

    }
}

private void teardownAlarm(Context context) {
    if (alarmIntent != null) {
        getAlarmManager(context).cancel(alarmIntent);
    }
}

private final AlarmManager getAlarmManager(Context context) {
    return (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
}

private static class WidgetRefresher {
    Context context;
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager;

    public WidgetRefresher(Context context,
            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager) {
        this.context = context;
        this.appWidgetManager = appWidgetManager;
    }

    public void refresh(int widgetId) {
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.widget);
        WidgetConfiguration config = getConfig(widgetId);

        SimpleDate eventDate = config.getSimpleDate();
        if (eventDate != null) {
            updateTextWithDate(views, eventDate);
        } else {
            updateTextWithoutDate(views);
        }

        updateTitle(views, config.getTitle());
        setupClickIntent(views, widgetId);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, views);
    }

    private void updateTextWithDate(RemoteViews views, SimpleDate date) {
        String daysLeft = Integer.toString(date.getDaysLeft());
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.eventDate, date.toString());
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.daysLeft, daysLeft);
    }

    private void updateTextWithoutDate(RemoteViews views) {
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.eventDate, "");
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.daysLeft, "");
    }

    private void updateTitle(RemoteViews views, String title) {
        if (title == null) {
            title = context.getString(R.string.no_title);
        }
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.eventTitle, title);
    }

    private WidgetConfiguration getConfig(int widgetId) {
        return new WidgetConfiguration(context, widgetId);
    }

    private void setupClickIntent(RemoteViews views, int widgetId) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ConfigureActivity.class);

        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, widgetId);

        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                widgetId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.eventTitle, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

}
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Free.daysleft